# Transform not working for SVG in IE browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use transform – translate in SVG. But it doesn’t work in IE browser. However, it working fine in Chrome. 
Here is my code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="border: 1px solid red">
<svg width="400" height="110" transform="translate(10, 29)">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
</svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Can any one help me to resolve this in IE browser.

Comment: hi which version of IE used .try to use latest version

Comment: @LDS, I am using version IE11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <body style="border: 1px solid red">
  <svg width="400" height="110">
   <g transform ="translate(10, 29)">
    <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
   </g>
  </svg>
 </body>
</html>
```